# install iperf3 ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, iperf

I hope to find an answer rather quickly about this issue. I am currently trying measure RTT from an iOS device to my ubuntu desktop and server. However, I'm seeing that the iperf version on iOS is iperf3 (which is probably the reason why I keep getting an error message every time I try to perform a simple test). I am able to ping from the iOS device to my hosts.

So right now,I am trying to install iperf3 into my Ubuntu 14.04 desktop and server (with the notion that having the same versions will resolve the problem), but keep getting an error that iperf is not installed.

When I do apt-get iperf, it installs. But when I go to check the version (iperf -vl), I get version 2.0.5-3.

Any help I get is greatly appreciated.

Comment: iperf is iperf version 2.0; the binary for iperf 3.x is called iperf3

Answer (score 24):

Apparently someone named Patrick Domack built a version for Ubuntu Trusty (14.04). *Edit: also works on 15.10.*

Copy-paste this command and press ENTER:

```
sudo add-apt-repository "ppa:patrickdk/general-lucid"
```

Resynchronize the package index files:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Install iperf:

```
sudo apt-get install iperf3
```

Invoke iperf version 3:

```
iperf3 -c iperf.scottlinux.com
```

Comment: Thank you so much! that saved me a lot of trouble.

Comment: If you get the error `The program add-apt-repository is currently not installed`, follow this answer: http://askubuntu.com/a/38035/301615

Answer (score 9):

```
apt-get install git-core  //install git tool

apt-get install make    //install make tool, to make iperf3

git clone https://github.com/esnet/iperf   //clone iperf3 source code

cd iPerf  //go to the iperf3 source code folder, and compile it

./configure

make

make install
```

Comment: maybe you need an additional
`apt-get install gcc`
if you have no compiler at all

Answer (score 7):

As of Vivid (15.04), `iperf3` is now available in the Ubuntu `universe` repository. It is also available with backports on Trusty (14.04). To get it:

```
sudo apt install iperf3
```

Here's a link to [the official package description](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/iperf3) on the Ubuntu website.

Answer (score 1):

Using this one-liner: will install required build tools, clone iperf3, build and install it:

```
apt-get install git-core build-essential && git clone https://github.com/esnet/iperf && cd iperf && ./configure && make && make install
```

Comment: not work for me. I got "iperf3: error while loading shared libraries: libiperf.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"

Answer (score 1):

If you want to install the latest version of iperf3 on your Ubuntu/Debian distro without compiling it from sources and without adding any repository (in ppa:patrickdk iperf3 version is 3.0.7) you can use instruction from [site](https://iperf.fr/iperf-download.php#more-recent).

```
sudo apt-get remove iperf3 libiperf0
wget https://iperf.fr/download/ubuntu/libiperf0_3.1.3-1_amd64.deb
wget https://iperf.fr/download/ubuntu/iperf3_3.1.3-1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libiperf0_3.1.3-1_amd64.deb iperf3_3.1.3-1_amd64.deb
rm libiperf0_3.1.3-1_amd64.deb iperf3_3.1.3-1_amd64.deb
```

I checked later and find that Ubuntu add that package to their official repo and it will be more preferable way to install in from them. I left that answer for people who need to install iperf3 on Ubuntu 12 and earlier versions.

Answer (score 1):

for proxy to be: ip: 172.16.2.30  port: 8080

pip --proxy=https://172.16.2.30:8080 install iperf3

non-proxy:

pip install iperf3

Answer (score 0):

apt-get one line:

```
add-apt-repository -y "ppa:patrickdk/general-lucid" && apt-get update && apt-get install -y iperf3
```

I use -y to make the script automatic run this command.

Answer (score 0):

If you are installing iperf3 onto a stock AWS EC2 Ubuntu image, you may also have to install a couple more packages to get it to run.  So in total the process looks like this:

1. sudo apt-get update
2. sudo apt-get install make
3. sudo apt-get install gcc --fix-missing
4. sudo apt-get install lib32z1
5. git clone https://github.com/esnet/iperf
6. cd iperf
7. ./configure
8. make
9. sudo make install
10. sudo ldconfig